# emacs svn tex file in mac os x

Tags: osx

I am using emacs for editing *.tex file. Tex file is controlled under svn.
I recently migrated to new macbook 12" with sub-c.

When I launch emacs from the shell, I do not have any problem in manipulating the tex file. When I launch the emacs clicking the icon in the launch bar, there occur two issue in manipulating the same tex file. They are executing the same emacs binary.

First, when the emacs is launched through icon click, the svn check-in fails. It says 
    svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at
    '/Users/...' (format 31).
    You need to get a newer Subversion client. For more details, see
     http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change

Second, in shell launched emacs, emacs shows the version number of the tex file in the bottom of its window. When the emacs is launched from the icon clock, i do not see any version number of the tex document.

I think the both issues are rooted at the same reason. I am just wondering if
I could get some clue.

Comment: Sounds like you might have two versions of Subversion client installed. One is somehow available to the shell started by your user (maybe it is mentioned in your Bash profile?) and another available to the rest of the users. When GUI Emacs starts, it doesn't execute your Bash profile, and this would explain the difference.

Comment: I think @wvxvw is right: the Mac OS X built-in svn (`/usr/bin/svn`) is very old and GUI Emacs will usually use it because unlike starting Emacs from shell, GUI Emacs doesn't know your PATH. this package (https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) is made to solve this problem.